# Check yum security updates using python

Tags: python, yum

Using the following code I can list all packages that have an update available:

```
import yum

base = yum.YumBase()
package_list = base.doPackageLists(pkgnarrow='updates', patterns='', ignore_case=True)

if package_list.updates:
  for pkg in package_list.updates:
    print(pkg)
```

but what I actually want is to list security updates only (equivalent of yum check-update --security).

Unfortunately I cannot find proper documentation about the yum library. Can someone help me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See  the [following script](http://people.redhat.com/jantill/yum/commands/yum-list-security-updates.py).

Short answer, you should use `UpdateMetadata` to filter the results based on the metadata of each notice.

```
import yum
from yum.update_md import UpdateMetadata
y = yum.YumBase()
ygh = y.doPackageLists('updates')    
x = UpdateMetadata()

for i in ygh.updates:
    md = x.get_notice((i.name, i.ver, i.rel))
    if md:
        md = md.get_metadata()
        if sec_only:
            if md['type'] != 'security':
                continue
```

(the code above is just a portion of the linked code, with the relevant bits)

Comment: Thanks! I got it working. I extended your code, since x.get_notice() won't work if x is not filled with data.

Comment: @Sinan as mentioned, code was incomplete. glad you got it working :)